# Some URLs need a trailing slash or it redirects to the home page

Tags: redirection

I have cloned my production site to a dev environment. Both are Drupal 7.58 running on a WIMP stack if that matters.

Both are using clean URLs. In the dev site this url http://mysite/about-us redirects to the home page. However the address bar continues to show http://mysite/about-us. This is true of any url that has one "directoy" level like: http://mysite/xxxx

If I add a trailing slash to the url then it works, http://mysite/about-us/ does properly render the About Us page. The production site does not have this problem, it renders the correct page with or without the trailing slash.

Urls like http://mysite/about-us/team also work without issue on either production or dev and with or without the slash. The home page also works fine.

Any idea why http://mysite/xxxx is rendering the home page?

Comment: What path is the front page set to in the Site Information config page?

Comment: Thanks for responding! The setting is: http://localhost:8581/home  I removed the "home" portion, changing it to nothing, but it didn't affect anything.

Comment: Ok, I was wondering if a View that was expecting and interpreting a contextual filter was set to the home page. You might try just setting one particular node as the front page and see if that changes the behavior.